# Mvc.DefaultFormControllerName - What does this setting do?

Tags: sitecore-forms

Using sitecore 9.3...

Im looking to override the Sitecore Experience Forms controller. I saw this setting (Mvc.DefaultFormControllerName) and was thinking I could just replace the value of this setting (The default value is "") and it would fire my controller instead of Sitecore's, but no luck. I tried just the controller name (without the word 'controller') and also the fully qualified name of the controller.

What does this setting do? Is it really for overriding the Experience Forms controller?

How do I use this setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That setting is not related to Sitecore Experience Forms.

It's a very old setting (originating in Sitecore 7) which is not well documented and (at least to my knowledge) not used commonly:

```
  <!--  MVC DEFAULT FORM CONTROLLER NAME
        Name of the default controller to invoke when handling form posts from renderings.
        An empty value means that renderings that contain empty Form Controller fields cannot handle form posts.
        Default value: ""
  -->
  <setting name="Mvc.DefaultFormControllerName" value="" />
```

It seems like if:

- you have a `<form>` tag in your rendering
- you don't specify any controller (action?) for the form
- and you set that setting value to some controller

Controller from the setting will be used for handling the form.

Comment: Ill create a new question for what I was actually trying to do.